# Regular expression in python: removing brackets with brackets inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, mediawiki, python-re

I have a wiktionary dump and struggling with finding appropriate regex pattern to remove the double brackets in the expression. Here is the example of the expressions:

`line = "# Test is a cool word {{source|{{nom w pc|Chantal|Bouchard}}, ''La langue et le nombril'', Presses de l'Université de Montréal (PUM), 2020, p. 174}}."`

I am looking to remove all of the brackets when is begins with {{source|:

Example :`# Test is a cool word.`

I tried using re.sub like this line = `re.sub("{{source\|.*?}}", "", line )`

but I got `# Test is a cool word, ''La langue et le nombril'', Presses de l'Université de Montréal (PUM), 2020, p. 174}}.`

I could also have another sentence like this `line = "# Test is a cool word {{source|Nicolas|Daniel, Presses de l'Université de Montréal 4}}"`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean you only want to do that with `re` library? If you need a regex, best is to use the PyPi regex library.

Comment: how to to it with PyPi regex ? I never used that

Comment: Can you have text you want to keep after the last `}}` or can you have multiple matches per sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the PyPi regex library (type `pip install regex` in the terminal/console and press ENTER), and then use

```py
import regex
rx = r"\s*{{source\|(?>[^{}]|({{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}}))*}}\s*"
line = "# Test is a cool word {{source|{{nom w pc|Chantal|Bouchard}}, ''La langue et le nombril'', Presses de l'Université de Montréal (PUM), 2020, p. 174}}."
print( regex.sub('', line) )
# => # Test is a cool word.
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LU9LasMwEN37FA93YTkxJkkLhUIbaLcNZNGs6gYUW8QCRTIjuXGRdaCcIwdz7bSbgXm/edP8uNro@2GQp8aQA4mj6CLq8AyKCzsrfOGtaakURc/WL597H756NqFs/XTb5vORWKbpLITbGE1xpKQWY0R8hw9hHaQFR2mMwtlQBf8f2XuvzQlnNGX/VnPtuOpfTVvWnKoQMiTJO4fi@tgKCAclMMoPJFWSZNiSsFZYVAIq2Wn5LchKd71MwMZoR9cLV2Db3SbNsFqsFhmaHMvHhxDyOGpIasf@3s1te2DUTfcyTM1TpFE0DL8).
The regex is

```py
\s*\{\{source\|(?>[^{}]|(\{\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}}))*}}\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mz2oG5/1/). Details:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `{{source\|` - a literal `{{source|` string
- `(?>[^{}]|({{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}}))*` - zero or more repetitions of:

  - `[^{}]` - a char other than `{` and `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `({{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}})` - Group 1 (it is necessary for recursion): `{{`, zero or more occurrences of any one or more chars other than `{{` and `}}` or the the Group 1 recursed, and then a `}}` string
- `}}` - a `}}` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The `.*?}}` subexpression will find the shortest possible string which ends with `}}`. If you want to skip pairs of `{{...}}` you have to say so.

```py
re.sub(r"\{\{source\|(?:\{\{.*?\}\})*.*?\}\}", "", line)
```

Note also that if you want to extend this to also handle additional levels of nesting, you have to spell that out explicitly, too; regular expressions are really not an adequate tool for handling nested structures, especially not arbitrarily nested structures. (This is a [common FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la))

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without a regular expression and cover all levels of embedded meta data.

```
line = "# Test is a cool word {{source|{{nom w pc|Chantal|Bouchard}}, ''La langue et le nombril'', Presses de l'Université de Montréal (PUM), 2020, p. 174}}."

from itertools import accumulate
levels = accumulate( (c=="{")-(p=="}") for c,p in zip(line," "+line) )
result = "".join(c for c,level in zip(line,levels) if level==0)

print(result)
# Test is a cool word .
```

This computes an incremental "level" of embedding that goes up with each "{" and back down after each "}".  Characters that are at level zero are part of the actual text and everything else is excluded.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following regex to obtain the desired answer.

```
\W+{{source\|.*}}
```

The code will be,

```
re.sub("\W+{{source\|.*}}", "", line )
```

The regular expression is almost same as the one in the question except the `?`. Removing the `?` makes it to match `.` as many times as possible.

Additionally, to remove the space before the `{{}}` the `\W+` is added.

Comment: If the text has multiple `{{source|...}}` occurrences, this will eat all the text between the first one and the last one.